# how to validate txt scanner data in java

Tags: java

i want to validate the client ID for only having integer and do not duplicated.
the txt file contain client details such as id,name and so on.
    public void loadClientData() {

```
    String fnm="", snm="", pcd="";
    int num=0, id=1;
    try {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File("clients.txt"));
        scnr.useDelimiter("\\s*#\\s*");
        //fields delimited by '#' with optional leading and trailing spaces  

        while (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
            id  = scnr.nextInt();
            snm = scnr.next();
            fnm = scnr.next();
            num = scnr.nextInt();
            pcd = scnr.next();

            //validate here type your own code

            if( id != scnr.nextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input! ");
                scnr.next();
            }   
        //some code...
        }
    }
}
```

it only print out the first client.

any help pls?

and also is it already validated?

this is the client.txt

```
0001#  Jones#          Jack#           41#   NX4 4XZ#
0002#  McHugh#         Hugh#           62#   SS3 3DF#
0003#  Wilson#         Jonny#          10#   LO4 4UP#
0004#  Heath#          Edward#         9#    LO4 4UQ#
0005#  Castle#         Brian#          15#   LO4 4UP#
0006#  Barber#         Tony#           11#   LO4 4UQ#
0007#  Nurg#           Fred#           56#   NE8 1ST#
0008#  Nurg#           Frieda#         56#   NE8 1ST#
0009#  Mouse#          Mickey#         199#  DD33 5XY#
0010#  Quite-Contrary# Mary#           34#   AB5 9XX#
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of clients.txt?

Answer (score 1):

From Java documentation for the Scanner class:

> public int nextInt()
>
> Scans the next token of the input as an int.
>
> An invocation of this method of the form nextInt() behaves in exactly
>   the same way as the invocation nextInt(radix), where radix is the
>   default radix of this scanner.
>
> Returns:
>       the int scanned from the input Throws:
>
> ```
> InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
> NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
> IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
> ```

The function will throw an `InputMismatchException` if the scanner reads invalid input that doesn't match an `Integer` regular expression.

You can use that exception for validation using `try - catch` block and handle the "error" the way you want

You also have other problems in your code. I modified it and put the explanation in comments

```
public static void loadClientData() {



 try {
        String fnm = "", snm = "", pcd = "";
        int num = 0, id = 1;
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File("clients.txt"));
        scnr.useDelimiter("\\s*#\\s*");
        //fields delimited by '#' with optional leading and trailing spaces
        //check for hasNext not hasNextInt since the next character might not be an integer
        while (scnr.hasNext()) {

            //here happens the integer validation

            try {
                id = scnr.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input !");
            }
            System.out.print(id + "  ");
            snm = scnr.next();
            System.out.print(snm + "  ");
            fnm = scnr.next();
            System.out.print(fnm + "  ");
            num = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.print(num + "  ");
            pcd = scnr.next();
            System.out.println(pcd + "  ");

            //you need to do this to get the scanner to jump to the next line
            if (scnr.hasNextLine()) {                    
                scnr.nextLine();
            }
            //validate here type your own code
            /* if (id != scnr.nextInt()) {
             System.out.println("Invalid input! ");
             //scnr.next();
             }*/

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}
```